# Did you miss me?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I feel most at home in Hannover
>   But I love travelling to Dover
>   Two years long we've seen another
>   Sometimes along with your mother
>   Peace was made many times
>   Over my people's insignificant crimes

**Who am I?**

hint:

> When you were young you came to me
> To play, to sing, to laugh, to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is wrong, but I just had to guess

> KINDERGARTEN?

I feel most at home in Hannover

> Kindergarten was [invented in Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindergarten).

But I love travelling to Dover

> It quickly spread to England afterwards.

Two years long we've seen another

> This could be Junior Kindergarten and Senior Kindergarten.

Sometimes along with your mother

> Parent-Teacher Interviews!

Peace was made many times

> Reconciling with your teachers and other slightly larger small children...

Over my people's insignificant crimes

> After all those fights and *my Goodness* stop waking me up during naptime and **teacher he stole my toys/crayons/lunch**!

Hint:

> When you were young you came to me 
>  **You go to kindergarten when you're young** 
>  To play, to sing, to laugh, to be 
>  **You do all of these things at kindergarten.**

Comment: You are close, but the answer and most of the clues are not correct.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure how I could have some of the clues correct...

Comment: you got it ;) but the clues are still a mess ;)

Comment: Working on it now! I'm almost done!

Comment: @Cashbee how does this look?

Comment: Well done! looks good!

Comment: @Cashbee According to **El-Guest**'s answer, this riddle might also need to include the `knowledge` tag, because I had no idea that Rot13(xvaqretnegra jnf vairagrq va Treznal)! :)

Comment: @user477343 Actually I had a slightly different different meaning on that and the following clue (Rot13)gur jbeq "xvaqretnegra" vf trezna ohg hfrq va gur ratyvfu ynathntr * I myself did not know what El-Guest said before neither ;)

Comment: @Cashbee hah, that's a coincidence :P